# How to hint that a FnOnce closure will be executed exactly once to avoid a "capture of possibly uninitialized variable" warning?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement and apply [an optimized `replace_with` helper for `Option`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2296#issuecomment-398723548). I have implemented it like this:

```
trait OptionExt<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn replace_with<F>(&mut self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(Option<T>) -> Option<T>;
}

impl<T> OptionExt<T> for Option<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn replace_with<F>(&mut self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(Option<T>) -> Option<T>,
    {
        let mut x = f(self.take());
        mem::swap(self, &mut x);
        debug_assert!(x.is_none());
        mem::forget(x);
    }
}
```

It works fine for a simple use-case.

Naive implementation:

```
let merged = merge(lower_node.right.take(), Some(greater_node));
lower_node.right = merged;
```

Optimized implementation ([details about the trick](https://barrielle.cedeela.fr/research_page/dropping-drops.html)):

```
let mut merged = merge(lower_node.right.take(), Some(greater_node));
mem::swap(&mut lower_node.right, &mut merged);
debug_assert!(merged.is_none());
mem::forget(merged);
```

Optimized implementation with a nicer interface:

```
lower_node.right.replace_with(|node| merge(node, Some(greater_node));
```

---

This doesn't play nicely when I want to implement a `split_binary` function that would return a pair of nodes:

Naive implementation:

```
let (left_node, right_node) = split_binary(orig_node.right.take(), value);
orig_node.right = left_node;
(Some(orig_node), right_node)
```

Optimized implementation:

```
let (mut left_node, right_node) = split_binary(orig_node.right.take(), value);
mem::swap(&mut orig_node.right, &mut left_node);
debug_assert!(left_node.is_none());
mem::forget(left_node);
(Some(orig_node), right_node)
```

Optimized implementation with a nicer interface (does not compile since `right_node` is now inside closure):

```
orig_node.right.replace_with(|node| {
    let (left_node, right_node) = split_binary(node, value);
    left_node
});
(Some(orig_node), right_node)
```

I can make it compile by defining a helper `new_right_node` outside of the closure:

```
let mut new_right_node = None;
orig_node.right.replace_with(|node| {
    let (left_node, right_node) = split_binary(node, value);
    new_right_node = right_node;
    left_node
});
(Some(orig_node), new_right_node)
```

I have to initialize `new_right_node` with `None` as otherwise Rust has an error "use of possibly uninitialized `new_right_node`". Yet doing this initialization results in an unnecessary `core::ptr::drop_in_place` call for the initial `None` value of `new_right_node`. Manually inlining the `replace_with`, I can get away without a need to initialize `new_right_node` upfront:

```
let new_right_node;
{
    let (mut left_node, right_node) = split_binary(orig_node.right.take(), value);
    new_right_node = right_node;
    mem::swap(&mut orig_node.right, &mut left_node);
    debug_assert!(left_node.is_none());
    mem::forget(left_node);
}
(Some(orig_node), new_right_node)
```

Thus, it seems that I can solve this efficiently if I can convince Rust that the closure will be executed and thus `new_right_node` will be initialized.

How can I solve this efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unsafe` since you know the value will always be initialized. Two `unsafe` functions come into play: [`mem::uninitialized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html), which disables the "possibly uninitialized" error, and [`ptr::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write.html), which lets you write to `new_right_node` without dropping the previous (uninitialized) value.

```
unsafe {
    let mut new_right_node = std::mem::uninitialized();
    orig_node.right.replace_with(|node| {
        let (left_node, right_node) = split_binary(node, value);
        std::ptr::write(&mut new_right_node, right_node);
        left_node
    });
}
```

I believe this is safe in the absence of panics because `new_right_node` is always initialized and `right_node` is moved into it without either one being dropped. However, to make it panic safe, you must also guarantee there's no way to observe `new_right_node` in its uninitialized state if `split_binary` panics.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It is unfortunate, that to make the API look nicer I have to go from mildly tricky `mem::*` calls to `unsafe` implementation :(

Comment: Yes, it's ugly. I'd have hoped the `drop` in `new_right_node = right_node;` would be optimized away when `new_right_node` is initialized to `None`.

Comment: I would update this example to use `MaybeUninit` now that it exists, since, according to its docs, "it is immediate undefined behavior to call [`mem::uninitialized`] on nearly all types, including integer types and arrays of integer types, and even if the result is unused."